# how to match a string of words using regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Am trying to find a regex expression for this result:

```
string => should be matched (a single word or set of words at the beginning or the ending)
 string  => should be matched (a single word or set of words in the middle)
{{string}} -- should not be matched (a single word or set of words surrounded by two "{}" should not be matched)
```

am using this regex in this function :

```
text = text.replace(RegExp("([^{]{2})[^(\d:)]" + aTags[index].textContent + "\w* 
([^}]{2})", 'i'), "{{" + index + ":" + aTags[index].textContent + "}}");
```

the function should find the textContent of an 'a' tag in a 'text' string and replace it by adding a digit and ':' to the beginning of the textContent so that the result should be something like this :

```
some text => will became => {{1:some text}}
```

[image: regex on regex101]

Comment: Try  `text.replace(RegExp("{{.*?}}|(" + aTags[index].textContent + ")\\w*", "i"), function($0, $1) { return $1 ? "{{" + index + ":" + $1 + "}}" : $0;} )`, see http://jsfiddle.net/4bpkzhtd/1/.

Comment: hi, thank you for your comment , the problem with your answer is that it match {{string}} witch i don't want to match it i need to skip it, this one : `text = text.replace(RegExp("{{[^}]+}}|(" + aTags[index].textContent + ")", 'gmi'), function (match, $1) { if($1) return $1 ? {{${index}:${$1}}} : match; });` worked on regex101 but in javascript i get this error `Invalid regular expression: /{{[^}]+}}|(*SKIP what's to avoid approach)/: Nothing to repeat`

Comment: You cannot "skip" anything in a **JavaScript** regex , it is not PCRE. You should match and capture it and then add some programming logic around it - see my snippet - doesn't it produce the results you need? In my snippet, I match `{{...}}`, but I do *skip* it in the code.

Comment: I strongly advise to first understand the basics of JS regex before trying to meddle with the regex testers, and be very careful with options you select there.

Comment: yes you right, i modified my code like this : `text = text.replace(RegExp("{{[^}]+}}|(" + aTags[index].textContent + ")", 'gmi'), function (match, $1) {
                return $1 ? `{{${index}:${$1}}}` : match;
            });` it worked now , thanks

Comment: Very frustrating to see it requires two people to explain things in every detail up to a point of providing a copy&pasteable solution. That essentially is a free coding service.

Comment: @wp78de Sorry, I did not even notice your answer (I think it is due to the one deleted that appeared on top).

Comment: It happens, thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use PCRE verbs like `(*SKIP)(*F)` in a JavaScript regex, i.e. you cannot skip a matched portion of text with the regex means only. In JavaScript, you may match and capture a part of the string you want to later analyze in the replacement callback method (JS [`String#replace` accepts a callback as the replacement argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)).

So, in your case the solution will look like

```
text = text.replace(RegExp("{{.*?}}|(" + aTags[index].textContent + ")", "gi"),
    function ($0, $1) { 
        return $1 ? "{{" + index + ":" + $1 + "}}" : $0; 
    }
);
```

I understand the `aTags[index].textContent` value is alphanumeric, else, consider [escaping it for use in a regex pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript).

The pattern will match a `{{...}}` substring having no `}` inside (with `{{.*?}}`) or (`|`) it will match and capture the text content (`(aTags[index].textContent)`) into Group 1. When you get a match, you need to pass 2 arguments to the callback, the whole match and Group 1 value. If Group 1 is not empty, you perform string manipulations, else, just insert the match back.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it worked finally, i need to read more on regex to understand them better

Answer (score 2):

We can apply the good old [*SKIP what's to avoid approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535912/8291949) and throw everything that does not need to be replaced in the full match and capture the desired output in group 1:

```
{{[^}]+}}|(string)
```

To make this work effectively in JavaScript we have to use a `.replace` callback function:

```js
const regex = /{{[^}]+}}|(string)/gm;
const str = `string 
 string  
{{string}}`;

var index = 1; //this is your index var and is somehow set from outside
const result = str.replace(regex, function(m, group1) {
    if (group1) return `{{${index}:${group1}}}`;
    else return m;
});
console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

I had pseudo-coded this a bit since I cannot know where `index` and `aTags[index].textContent` is coming from. Adjust as needed.

Comment: hi , thank you for your answer, i modified my code to match you answer but i get this error : Invalid regular expression: /{{[^}]+}}|(*SKIP what's to avoid approach)/: Nothing to repea , here is the function :
text = text.replace(RegExp("{{[^}]+}}|(" + aTags[index].textContent + ")", 'gmi'), function (match, $1) {
                if($1) return $1 ? `{{${index}:${$1}}}` : match;
            });

Comment: @j.sell sorry, you totally misinterpreted the pseudo-code. Fortunately, you are already covered.